# Kettle: Calculate length of column

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I have following Kettle transformation:

[image]

[image]

The output is:

```
2017/06/02 14:51:10 - Write to log.0 - ------------> Linenr 1------------------------------
2017/06/02 14:51:10 - Write to log.0 - Text = This is line 1
2017/06/02 14:51:10 - Write to log.0 - Length =  11
2017/06/02 14:51:10 - Write to log.0 - Copy = [B@709B5D90
2017/06/02 14:51:10 - Write to log.0 - 
2017/06/02 14:51:10 - Write to log.0 - ====================
2017/06/02 14:51:10 - Write to log.0 - 
2017/06/02 14:51:10 - Write to log.0 - ------------> Linenr 2------------------------------
2017/06/02 14:51:10 - Write to log.0 - Text = This is line 2 and is longer
2017/06/02 14:51:10 - Write to log.0 - Length =  11
2017/06/02 14:51:10 - Write to log.0 - Copy = [B@7E5CADF3
2017/06/02 14:51:10 - Write to log.0 - 
2017/06/02 14:51:10 - Write to log.0 - ====================
2017/06/02 14:51:10 - Write to log.0 - 
2017/06/02 14:51:10 - Write to log.0 - ------------> Linenr 3------------------------------
2017/06/02 14:51:10 - Write to log.0 - Text = This is line 3 and is much longer
2017/06/02 14:51:10 - Write to log.0 - Length =  11
2017/06/02 14:51:10 - Write to log.0 - Copy = [B@7A6336E0
```

It seems kettle refers to the column "Text" by its hashcode instead of its value. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the field type of Text when it comes out of the CSV input? Actually, this rings a bell. Try turning off Lazy conversion if it's checked in the CSV input.

Comment: @Cyrus Thank you! That was it. Disabling `lazy conversion` fixed it. Would you like to put that as an answer I can accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values you see are not hashcodes but references to raw data. This happens when the input step has **Lazy conversion** enabled. The Calculator step should be triggering the conversion to strings but for some reason it is skipped in this case.

Uncheck Lazy conversion in the CSV input step to fix it.